# How to write same functionality as app.get('/') only in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building app with `javascript` and `node.js`.

When I want to open homepage I will do this with `express`:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

And on this way, when I open homepage it would return me `index.html`

But I'm wondering how to do same thing only with `Nodejs` without `express`.

I suppose that I need to create server first, and then to return `index.html` page somehow when request is `/`, although I'm not sure is this correct approach.

```
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
});

server.on('request', (request, response)=> {
  if (requsest.url == '/') {
    response.end('index.html')
  }
 });
```

Above written code is my way of thinking about it, probably not correct way, so please if some one can give me idea or solution how should I do this in `Nodejs`.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

It just renders a static file `index.html`

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('./index.html', function(err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        response.writeHeader(200, {
            "Content-Type": "text/html"
        });
        response.write(html);
        response.end();
    }).listen(3000);
});
```

assuming your folder structure

```
project root 
     ├── server.js
     ├── package.json 
     └── index.html
```

For basic routing in `Node.js` without using framework `express`. You need to set up your `server.js` file making the use of `switch` case block for various routes. Simple Example:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const port = 3000;
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
    let htmlFile = '';
    switch (req.url) {
        case '/':
            htmlFile = 'index.html';
            break;
        case '/about':
            htmlFile = 'about.html';
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    if (htmlFile)
        render(res, htmlFile);
});

function render(res, htmlFile) {
    fs.stat(`./${htmlFile}`, (err, stats) => {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
        if (stats) {
            fs.createReadStream(htmlFile).pipe(res);
        } else {
            res.statusCode = 404;
            res.end('Page not found!');
        }
    });
}
```

- `index.html` on accessing root path `/`.
- `about.html` on accessing `/about`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. This was answer to my question. Now I just wondering, is this good approach to do application in Nodejs. I want to create application in which on page requests, I will serve some response. And I know that in expressjs that is the way how we build applications and how we think about application.
In `express` we should create `routes` and then add `handlers` function to respond on requests for those `routes`.
But what si way of doing it in Nodejs how to think about application in `Nodejs` way, not in `expressjs` way.

Comment: I think you are talking about basic routing in `node.js` without using `express.js` so, I tried to explain with example have a look.